# How to check if column with name is valid by regex?

Tags: python, pandas

How to check if column with name is valid by regex in Pandas:

I have tried this way:

```
r = df['ADDRESS'].str.findall('^((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]))[.\/\\\\-]*([0-9]{2})[.\/\\\\]([1|2][0-9]{3})$')

if not r:
   df['ADDRESS'] = "Bird"
```

It does not work for meю

My goas is to move values from columns to specifci columns by content.

Exmaple is:

```
ID NAME         EMAIL
1  @GMAIL.COM   Inigma
@  Mary         4
```

As result I should arrange values by columns names:

```
ID NAME         EMAIL
1  Inigma       @GMAIL.COM
2  Mary         @
```

Comment: What constitutes a "valid" name?

Comment: It shoud be a address no matter any reg express

Comment: Can you provide some examples of vaild and invalid names?

Comment: Invalid `01/12/1991` or `442424` or `444`.
 `Valid` is string with at least one number (user address)

Comment: It can be any regex, I ask how to apply this and check specific column if is true

Comment: My goal is to find address and birthday in columns. If they not in right positions - chnage them